# accessing ubuntu files(installed in virtualbox) from windows

Tags: python, django, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 13.x in Virtual box

My parent OS is windows 8.1 . I need to access python files from IDE in windows. They are basically site packages directory like django .

eg:

```
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
```

How can i access it from parent os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to do :

1. get your host/guest machines connected to the same network. MAY be NAT or Bridge your VM with your physical adapter.
2. Install samba and create a samba share.
3. access your files from a windows machine via networks or smb:// protocol

Answer (score -1):

You can set up "Shared Folders" for the the Virtualbox image.

But a more convenient way might be to do it the opposite way around, i.e. having the folder locally on your host OS and sharing it to your guest. 
Have a look at this link, specifially for Django as you pointed out to be interested in: http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/en/lessons/introduction-and-launch/